# convert two times API call to one and use its data in two components

Tags: angular, algorithm, rxjs

I have components with name Product, Additional and Payment.
imagine after submit a form from ProductComponent I wanna call API to bring some data then check if **data.lenght** is more than one route changes to AdditionalComponent else route changes to PaymentComponent.
But the problem is there I need this API call data in AdditionalComponent so I must call again in this component. Is there any way to do this scenario with only one time API call

> I know about pipe shareReplay but is not useful in this scenario

service

```
getData(x, y) {
  return this.http.get(`/data?id=x&age=y`);
}
```

product.component.ts

```
submit() {
  this.service.getData(order.id, order.age).subscribe((data) => {
    if (data.lenght) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(`/additional`);
    }
    else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(`/payment`);
    }
  })
}
```

additional.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getData(order.id, order.age).subscribe((data) => {
    this.additionalData = data 
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options. You could use the singleton service to cache the response and retrieve it from both the components. Or option 2, which I'll illustrate here allows you to send any information between two routes as parameters.

**product.component.ts**

```js
submit() {
  this.service.getData(order.id, order.age).subscribe((data) => {
    if (data.length) {
      this.router.navigate([`/additional`, {data: JSON.stringify(data)}]);
    }
    else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(`/payment`);
    }
  })
}
```

**additional.component.ts**

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class AdditionalComponent implements OnInit {
  additionalData: any;

  constructor(private _actRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.additionalData = JSON.parse(this._actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('data'));
  }
}
```